# aws ec2 run infinite time job remotely

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS EC2 instance on which I would like to run a job of infinite time. However, I don't want to have to SSH into my instance to run the command.

I basically need to run a python script, which performs work indefinitely, so I want to run `python3 script.py` from my EC2 instance in such a way that I can do it remotely, and as long as my instance is running the `script.py` script is running.

To be more clear, if I run a command like `sudo service httpd start` I don't have to remain SSHed into my instance to know that the traffic is being served. Similarly, I would like to run a command such that even if I terminate my SSH connection to the instance, `script.py` is still running.

A solution I thought of is to have a local machine explicitly connect to the instance and run the command in an infinite loop, but I would like to avoid this.

A further question is if there is a way to scale to multiple instances performing this same job.

I have also tried editing `rc.local` in the `etc` directory, but I confirmed that the job was not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally to fully automate your application so that it scales onto new instances and **restarts after instance** start/stop/reboot, you would have to create your own [custom systemd unit](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-systemd-service-unit-in-linux). The unit file would be responsible for running your scripts and starting it automatically when it needs to.

To make everything **fully automated** you would have to setup your scripts and the unit files in [userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), preferably in a custom [launch template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchTemplates.html) which could form basis for your [autoscaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html).

Comment: If I save an AMI for the instance as it is currently executing the job without passing in the shell script (user data) for running the desired python script, will I still get the desired behavior?

Comment: @user100123122 If you make an AMI of instance who works like this, it will still work. Custom AMIs are a way for you to create instance which work exactly as you want.

Comment: Will it work if I SSH into my instance, run the python script, and then create an AMI in the AWS EC2 console?

Comment: @user100123122 Yes, if you setup your ` custom systemd unit` files so that your scripts start at boot time. I would suggest trying that and then making new question if you get some issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really python or aws related, it's more of a Linux question. In saying that, there are numerous options to achieving what you want.

If you simply want to run a program that persists (keeps running) after you've logged out of the system you can use bg + disown.

For example:

```
$ python script.py
ctrl-z
$ bg
$ disown -h
$ exit
```

You start your command as normal, press ctrl-z on your keyboard which suspends that task.

Next you call `bg` which switches the last suspended task to run in the background.

Following on from that you run `disown -h`, this removes the process from the control of the current shell (which will allow it to persist once you exit ssh).

Lastly, you can safely exit ssh and your process will continue running indefinitely.

There are a number other options you can use but this one of the easiest.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this programmatically, or am I required to manually log on to my EC2 instance? I am stuck on how to convert ctrl-z to a programmatic implementation.

Comment: If you want to do it programmatically you could run your script from cron. This will start the script at a specified schedule. Alternatively, you could run your script as a system daemon - have a look at the documentation for RHEL, the process is very similar to Amazon Linux https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-managing_services_with_systemd#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are asking for a way to start a script on an EC2 instance, and have it keep running after you terminate your SSH connection.

You can use [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) for this. Type `tmux new` to start a new tmux session, then run whatever script you are trying to run. Then press `Ctrl+B`, and then press `D`. This will disconnect you from your tmux session, but the tmux session will still be running your script. Now you can safely close your SSH connection, with your script still running. If you want to access the terminal running the script again, you can type `tmux a` into your console, and it will bring back the session running the script.

Alternatively, you can use [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), though I would use tmux for this task.